# Show that $\dim(CS(A)) + \dim(NS(A)) = n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

[image]

I tried to do this based on that $ \dim_F(V)-\dim_F(Nu(T))=\dim_F(IM(T))$ where $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to a vector space. Can I use this identity? Since as each matrix has associated a linear transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Define $T_A \colon \mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^m$ by $T_A(x) = Ax$ (left multiplication of $A$ by column vectors in $\mathbb{F}^n$). Then show that $\operatorname{CS}(A) = \operatorname{Im}(T_A)$ and $\operatorname{NS}(A) = \operatorname{Null}(T_A)$ and use the rank-nullity theorem.